# How to call a pointer of member function C++

Tags: c++

I get Expected unqualified-id from xcode of this piece of code.
I'm working with cocos2d-x 3.x but it's not related to this question.

in CCNode.h

```
virtual float getGlobalZOrder() const { return _globalZOrder; }
```

in my cpp

```
typedef float (Node::*SomeFunc)() const;
SomeFunc f = &Node::getGlobalZOrder;
Node * node = .....;
node->(*f)();  <-Expected unqualified-id
```

why I get the compile error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pointer-to-member dereferencing operators such as `.*` and `->*` is an integral operator, you can't seperate them by `()`. You can try this:

```
(node->*f)();
```

Comment: omg your code works! I tried (node->(*f))(); and it gives error... why it doesn't like () after ->..

Comment: @h5nc Because `->*` is an actual, whole operator in C++, and by cutting it up with pars you changed the meaning from "invoke member function through pointer" to something that didn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

use like below:

```
typedef float (Node::*SomeFunc)() const;
SomeFunc f = &Node::getGlobalZOrder;
Node * node = new Node();
float x = (node->*f)();
```